# Wordpress Access denied for user root with MySQL container

Tags: docker, docker-container

I'm trying to make MySQL instance available to other containers, I'm following this documentation [mysql](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) and this [wordpress](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/) official documentation, I get this error

> MySQL Connection Error: (1045) Access denied for user 'root'@'172.17.0.3' (using password: YES)

Code for MySQL instance

```
docker run -d --restart on-failure -v hatchery:/var/lib/mysql \
           -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=Kerrigan \
           -e MYSQL_DATABASE=zerglings --name spawning-pool mysql
```

Code for WordPress instance

```
docker run -d --name lair -p 8080:80 --link spawning-pool:mysql wordpress
```

How can I successfully link wordpress and mysql containers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it by deleting everything and try starting it up again.

```
docker rm -v spawning-pool # -v Remove the volumes associated with the container
```

Remove the volume too

```
docker volume rm hatchery
```

Then I created the containers again

```
# create the volume
docker volume create hatchery

# MySQL instance
docker run -it -d --restart on-failure -v hatchery:/var/lib/mysql \
           -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=Kerrigan \
           -e MYSQL_DATABASE=zerglings --name spawning-pool mysql

# creating wordpress
docker run -d --name lair -p 8080:80 --link spawning-pool:mysql \
           -e WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=mysql -e WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=zerglings 
           -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=Kerrigan wordpress
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass in your database connection credentials via environment variables to wordpress:

```
docker run -d --name lair -p 8080:80 --link spawning-pool:mysql \
    -e WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=mysql \
    -e WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=zerglings \
    -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=zerglings wordpress
```